# How can I control the value in one field based on the other field?

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-field, dynamic, dynamic-forms

[image]I am new to the salesforce , please help me to get fix for the below requirement.
As marked in the image,the Chapter is a lookup field which needs to show up values based on Subchapter/Division field. Basically, if the subchapter is null then Chapter value should populate. How can I make Chapter field dynamic?
I just want to display Rule w/o Subchapter section[Chapter Field] only when Subchapter/Division is null.
Please find the attached image for the reference.[image] - erroneous image is when added lookup filter on Chapter field, and then edited the record by selected subchapter/Division filed.
The lookup filter is filtering the data where subchapter is null.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited the description, please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: you can use lookup filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced the lookup file with formula by giving condition to show the data based on the above subchapter field. Thank you for all your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the look-up filter with appropriate criteria in which you can compare the value of other field (like null check).

Edit look-up field > Add lookup filter

Comment: I tried adding lookup filter, i am getting error when i try to add subchapter back, please see attached image.